# Como pegar a ultima query executada pelo CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, query, log, debug

Quero pegar a ultima query executada pelo CakePHP

Exemplo

```
$data  =  $this->Ticket->find('all',  array('conditions'  =>  $conditions,  'order'  =>  array('Ticket.id'  =>  'DESC')));

$this->query = $this->Ticket->getLastQuery();

public function getLastQuery($fromWhereClause = false){
        $dbo = $this->getDatasource();
        $logs = $dbo->getLog();
        $lastLog = end($logs['log']);
        if ($fromWhereClause) {
            return strstr($lastLog['query'], 'WHERE');
        }
        return $lastLog['query'];
}
```

mas o getLastQuery só é executada quando o debug está setado para o valor 2
gostaria de conseguir com o valor setado para 0

Comment: Só funciona com debug ativado, porque usa o log do debug do cake, até aonde eu sei, precisaria implementar algo assim direto no Model da lib.

Comment: Aparentemente sua função está OK, porém isto aqui funciona -<?php  end($this->ModelName->getDataSource()->getLog()['log'])['query']?>, considerando que você esteja executando este código no controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
$data  =  $this->Ticket->find('all',  array('conditions'  =>  $conditions,  'order'  =>  array('Ticket.id'  =>  'DESC')));

$this->query = $this->Ticket->getLastQuery();

public function getLastQuery($fromWhereClause = false){
    $dbo = $this->getDatasource();
    $dbo->fullDebug = true;
    $logs = $dbo->getLog();
    $lastLog = end($logs['log']);
    if ($fromWhereClause) {
        return strstr($lastLog['query'], 'WHERE');
    }
    $dbo->fullDebug = false;
    return $lastLog['query'];
}
```

Baseado nesta resposta do SOen:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14981941/echo-this-elementsql-dump-without-debug-and-in-a-mail